# Android Socket communication error

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am writing a small app in which android device tries to send a packet to server(which is my own computer).

I get some error, I dont know how to fix it.

Here is the error:

```
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >com.amazon.hsyal.WifiSimulatorActivity$1.onClick(WifiSimulatorActivity.java:33)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3536)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14130)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4495)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>07-02 14:58:56.125: E/AndroidRuntime(17976):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native >Method)
```

My android program is:

```
    public class WifiSimulatorActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button send_packet_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_packet_button);
        send_packet_button.setOnClickListener(sendPacketListener);

    }
    Button.OnClickListener sendPacketListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.52.138", 12345);
                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                output.write("Sending packet 1");

                s.close();
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
}

    public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
    Boolean end = false;
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
    System.out.println("Program running");
    while(!end){
            //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
            String st = input.readLine();
           System.out.println("Tcp Example From client: "+st);
            output.println("Good bye and thanks for all the fish :)");
            s.close();

    }
ss.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

In your case You are running Network operation from MainUI thread that's why you got this Exceptions (In android never allowed that). Use [Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put your Network (Socket code) in `doInBackGround()` of AsyncTask.

Look at SO question [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: With help of your answer that error is fixed but still my program is not working, when ever I create server socket and watch the socket address by calling getLocalSocketAddress, I see: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:53074

Answer (score 1):

As docs says: android.os.[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) :

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.

So try to implement  your Network relative code by Using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)